# what is the technology that undergirds Google's direct query answering

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, google-search, google-knowledge-graph

For instance, if I type the words

```
"chinese character question"
```

into Google I get this:

[image]

what is the technology that powers the displaying of `题` and Google translate directly?

Does this use some kind of "*knowledge graph*" or "*knowledge vault*"?

i.e. some kind of "*Semantic Web*" or `schema.org` infrastructure, RDF or w/e

Comment: It's the so called "Knowledge Cards". Please refer to here: http://www.seobythesea.com/2015/03/googles-knowledge-cards/. It's a kind of knowledge base, or knowledge management technology.

Comment: wow- what an excellent blog post- thank you :)